# android - ArrayAdapter not updating, but Sqlite Database updated

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am working on restaurant app.
In that, i have cart activity. 
That, I manage with the database. When the user adds an item, i insert it to a database.

I created one class that extends ArrayAdapter

- in this class, i display data of each item in the cart.
- when user finalizes cart items, i post it to WebService.

**Problem**

- in this cart, itemi have a button "remove this item."
- when I click on it, item is deleted from the database but not
  reflecting on ArrayList.

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working.

**NOTE**

when I go back to that activity and come, it will be removed.

Comment: PUT your code here, people dislike your question .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the item from Arraylist.

```
yourArraylist.remove(poistion);
```

Then you notify to adpter changed by below code

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try this it may help you.....